# amp-ima-video status detection event?

Tags: javascript, amp-html

How can I detect amp-ima-video has paused, resumed, ended?

What about programmatically play, pause, resume video using event?

```html
<amp-ima-video
  width="640"
  height="360"
  layout="responsive"
  data-tag="ads.xml"
  data-poster="poster.png"
>
  <source src="foo.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="foo.webm" type="video/webm" />
  <track
    label="English subtitles"
    kind="subtitles"
    srclang="en"
    src="subtitles.vtt"
  />
  <script type="application/json">
    {
      "locale": "en",
      "numRedirects": 4
    }
  </script>
</amp-ima-video>
```